# Google Spreadsheet trigger programmatically added is not

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to process values submitted from a Google Form when they get saved in the associated spreadsheet. I have an app script associated with the form (as it adds an addon menu there and is suppose to be used from FormApp), and this one **install the trigger on destination spreadsheet** as following.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').
  forSpreadsheet(destId).onFormSubmit().create();

function onFormSubmit(e) { Logger.log("--> submit"); }
```

I also have added an email notification (Immediate) on the trigger.

The trigger appears in project triggers. Calling the `onFormSubmit` function from editor, or on other event, is working and debug statement is written in the log.

When the form is POSTed, I don't either see anything in the log, nor receive any mail notification.

What's wrong there?

Comment: Try to set the notification to "immediately" ( in resource/triggers/this script triggers) and see if you get an error message.

Comment: also manually run the trigger from the debugger

Comment: The notification is already to Immediate. And the function is working perfectly when called in editor, of by a Form trigger. That's the trigger in Spreadsheet which is not working.